# Ruby: How to find nested object that matches certain attributes

Tags: json, ruby, find

My ruby is quite rusty and I'm having a hard time parsing through some JSON that I'm getting back from an HTTParty call in ruby. Currently, I am trying to get the 'ladderId' properties value that is deeply nested in a parsed JSON response.

```
response = HTTParty.get('myApiUrlHere')
json = JSON.parse(response.body)

ladder_id = ## // find within the "CurrentSeason" object a "ladder"  
            ## // object whose "league" property has the value
            ## //  "GRANDMASTER", and return that objects ladder ID
```

If my wording is confusing, I should expect the value "197606" when given the following JSON return

```
{
    "currentSeason": [{
        "ladder": [{
            "ladderName": "Alzadar Theta",
            "ladderId": 197606,
            "division": 5,
            "rank": 65,
            "league": "DIAMOND",
            "matchMakingQueue": "LOTV_TWOS",
            "wins": 8,
            "losses": 2,
            "showcase": true
        }],
        "characters": [{
            "id": 989277,
            "realm": 1,
            "displayName": "Warren",
            "clanName": "PSISTORM Gaming",
            "clanTag": "PSISTM",
            "profilePath": "/profile/989277/1/Warren/"
        }, {
            "id": 5220949,
            "realm": 1,
            "displayName": "True",
            "clanName": "PSISTORM Gaming",
            "clanTag": "PSISTM",
            "profilePath": "/profile/5220949/1/True/"
        }],
        "nonRanked": []
    }, {
        "ladder": [{
            "ladderName": "Kerrigan Kilo",
            "ladderId": 197160,
            "division": 1,
            "rank": 95,
            "league": "MASTER",
            "matchMakingQueue": "LOTV_TWOS_COMP",
            "wins": 1,
            "losses": 0,
            "showcase": true
        }],
        "characters": [{
            "id": 3650249,
            "realm": 1,
            "displayName": "CranK",
            "clanName": "Axiom eSports",
            "clanTag": "Ax",
            "profilePath": "/profile/3650249/1/CranK/"
        }, {
            "id": 5220949,
            "realm": 1,
            "displayName": "True",
            "clanName": "PSISTORM Gaming",
            "clanTag": "PSISTM",
            "profilePath": "/profile/5220949/1/True/"
        }],
        "nonRanked": []
    }, {
        "ladder": [],
        "characters": [{
            "id": 2238820,
            "realm": 1,
            "displayName": "Sugar",
            "clanName": "PSISTORM Gaming",
            "clanTag": "PSISTM",
            "profilePath": "/profile/2238820/1/Sugar/"
        }, {
            "id": 2481800,
            "realm": 1,
            "displayName": "starkiller",
            "clanName": "Ørdo Equitum",
            "clanTag": "ØE",
            "profilePath": "/profile/2481800/1/starkiller/"
        }, {
            "id": 5220949,
            "realm": 1,
            "displayName": "True",
            "clanName": "PSISTORM Gaming",
            "clanTag": "PSISTM",
            "profilePath": "/profile/5220949/1/True/"
        }],
        "nonRanked": [{
            "mmq": "LOTV_THREES",
            "gamesPlayed": 2
        }]
    }, {
        "ladder": [{
            "ladderName": "Carrier Zeta",
            "ladderId": 197921,
            "division": 1,
            "rank": 1,
            "league": "GRANDMASTER",
            "matchMakingQueue": "LOTV_SOLO",
            "wins": 187,
            "losses": 51,
            "showcase": true
        }],
        "characters": [{
            "id": 5220949,
            "realm": 1,
            "displayName": "True",
            "clanName": "PSISTORM Gaming",
            "clanTag": "PSISTM",
            "profilePath": "/profile/5220949/1/True/"
        }],
        "nonRanked": []
    }],
    "previousSeason": [{
        "ladder": [{
            "ladderName": "Marine Foxtrot",
            "ladderId": 196150,
            "division": 1,
            "rank": 35,
            "league": "MASTER",
            "matchMakingQueue": "LOTV_TWOS_COMP",
            "wins": 4,
            "losses": 5,
            "showcase": false
        }, {
            "ladderName": "War Pigs Foxtrot",
            "ladderId": 196853,
            "division": 11,
            "rank": 73,
            "league": "DIAMOND",
            "matchMakingQueue": "LOTV_TWOS",
            "wins": 2,
            "losses": 0,
            "showcase": false
        }],
        "characters": [{
            "id": 3650249,
            "realm": 1,
            "displayName": "CranK",
            "clanName": "Axiom eSports",
            "clanTag": "Ax",
            "profilePath": "/profile/3650249/1/CranK/"
        }, {
            "id": 5220949,
            "realm": 1,
            "displayName": "True",
            "clanName": "PSISTORM Gaming",
            "clanTag": "PSISTM",
            "profilePath": "/profile/5220949/1/True/"
        }],
        "nonRanked": []
    }, {
        "ladder": [{
            "ladderName": "Mutalisk Echo",
            "ladderId": 196647,
            "division": 1,
            "rank": 3,
            "league": "GRANDMASTER",
            "matchMakingQueue": "LOTV_SOLO",
            "wins": 134,
            "losses": 38,
            "showcase": false
        }],
        "characters": [{
            "id": 5220949,
            "realm": 1,
            "displayName": "True",
            "clanName": "PSISTORM Gaming",
            "clanTag": "PSISTM",
            "profilePath": "/profile/5220949/1/True/"
        }],
        "nonRanked": []
    }, {
        "ladder": [],
        "characters": [{
            "id": 2238820,
            "realm": 1,
            "displayName": "Sugar",
            "clanName": "PSISTORM Gaming",
            "clanTag": "PSISTM",
            "profilePath": "/profile/2238820/1/Sugar/"
        }, {
            "id": 5220949,
            "realm": 1,
            "displayName": "True",
            "clanName": "PSISTORM Gaming",
            "clanTag": "PSISTM",
            "profilePath": "/profile/5220949/1/True/"
        }],
        "nonRanked": [{
            "mmq": "LOTV_TWOS_COMP",
            "gamesPlayed": 2
        }]
    }]
}
```

Comment: We expect to see a better example of your attempt to solve the problem. Currently your code doesn't attempt to retrieve anything from the parsed data. Please read "[ask]" including the linked pages, "[mcve]" including the minimum code demonstrating your attempt to solve the problem. Also, reduce the JSON sample to the bare minimum to demonstrate the problem. Anything beyond that wastes our time. "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)" is also useful reading.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its pretty weird JSON, following code should work for your requirement:

```
obj = JSON.parse('your json string')
desired_obj = obj["currentSeason"].select do |i| 
     !i["ladder"][0].nil? && 
     i["ladder"][0]['league'] == 'GRANDMASTER'
end

ladder_id = desired_obj[0]['ladder'][0]['ladderId']
#=> 197921
```

Comment: Thanks Wand Maker, this worked perfectly!

And I agree that its pretty weird JSON... working with external API's always brings me something new. I appreciate your help.